# why Monit create multiple process if it already running

Tags: linux, bash, monit

`myscript.sh` is running then I start Monit with config

```
set daemon 20 with start delay 5
check program myscript with path "/home/myscript.sh"
  if status != 0 then exec "/home/myscript.sh"
```

or

```
set daemon 20 with start delay 5
check program myscript with path "/bin/bash /home/myscript.sh"
  if status != 0 then exec "/home/myscript.sh"
```

is my config wrong? why monit  create new process

```
# ps -ef | grep myscript.sh
root  1580  1571  0 13:29    ?    /bin/bash /home/myscript.sh < created by monit
root  32675 15735  0 13:23 pts/2  /bin/bash /home/myscript.sh
```